# Appropriate usage of cudaGetSymbolAddress and cudaMemcpyToSymbol with global memory?

Tags: cuda

I am fairly new to `CUDA` and am familiar with the normal usage of `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` and also with `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` for copying to constant memory.

However, I have just been given some code which makes frequent use of `cudaGetSymbolAddress` and `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` to copy to global memory and I'm not sure why they have chosen to do this instead of `cudaMalloc`/`cudaMemcpy`.

Would somebody be able to explain when it is advantageous and appropriate to use `cudaGetSymbolAddress` and `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When global memory is allocated dynamically using `cudaMalloc`, then the correct copying API to use is `cudaMemcpy`.

When global memory is allocated [statically](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#variable-type-qualifiers):

```
__device__  int my_data[DSIZE];
```

then the correct API to use is `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` or `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol`

Comment: Worth noting that `cudaMemcpy` can also be used with statically declared device memory if you call `cudaGetSymbolAddress`. If there are multiple operations, it might be marginally faster to only do the symbol lookup once.